# Не подгружается изображение (новая reCAPTCHA)

Tags: html, google-api, recaptcha

Проблема в новой reCAPTCHA (с галочкой): когда появляется окошко вывода картинки — браузер её не отображает:

[image: Скриншот проблемы]

Вид картинки такой:

```html
<img src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/payload?c=03AHJ_Vuu0dP5g9Zr1B1Xi82l656shcDwsg0gdJLU....QiDW8_y9KDy_hiL93e8o6dImUwuhGAW08FalZHJLa8eALUeyIT1PkfPyMTkJq_J93N_8ABV82x2dYTcCaG5qUosYw5humjULQ5yCIB61VQmPi8wRjr" alt="reCAPTCHA challenge image">
```

При попытке открыть этот URL также не видно изображения.
А если нажать «Открыть в новой вкладке» — видно.

В чём может быть проблема?